# replace &nbsp; between curly brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using liquid inside html editor.

I have issue when I do copy paste or different cases I have issue.

```js
var str = "{% if user.firstName = 'joe' || user.firstName = 'ben'&nbsp;%}";
console.log(str.replace(/(\{)\s*(\S+)\s*(?=})/img, "$1$2"));
```

It should output:

```
{% if user.firstName = 'joe' || user.firstName = 'ben' %}
```

I've tried : `str.replace(/(\{)\s*(\S+)\s*(?=})/img, "$1$2");`

Comment: Simply do: `String.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');`. [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 0):

Regex to replace non breaking spaces `&nbsp;`

```
var r = new RegExp('(&nbsp;)','g');
var s = "{% if user.firstName = 'joe' || user.firstName = 'ben' %}"
console.log(s.replace(r,''));
// {% if user.firstName = 'joe' || user.firstName = 'ben' %}
```

Comment: but i want to remove "&nbsp;" only between braces

Comment: please someone can  help me to find the right regex for this issue?